# What is the proper way to nest PHP scripts?

Tags: php, validation, styles, nested

So I've been making my own website for awhile, and have been trying to find a good way to set up PHP scripts so that it's not too cluttered. I've come across two ways to 'nest' the scripting so that it won't continue running if it comes across an error, but was just wondering which would be better to avoid scripting injection, or if either way wouldn't matter.

Option A (Run the page down the line):

```
function callExit($error) {
    //Close Database
    exit($error);
}
if (!$_POST['title']) { callExit("No title."); }
if (!$_POST['body']) { callExit("No body."); }
//Continue Script
```

Or Option B (Lots of nesting):

```
if ($_POST['title']) {
    if ($_POST['body']) {
        //Continue Script
    } else {
        //Close Database
    }
} else {
    //Close Database
}
```

Or Something Different?

Comment: Is this for validation? you could loop the `$_POST` data and check if the fields that must be set are there and aren't empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of people seem to worry about this, especially in PHP. Essentially, what you are saying is, how can I add a layer of abstraction to my application/program?

You can use an existing Validation framework. I won't name frameworks, but you can find them.

You can also invent your own validation class/function that would abstract away this "low level" boilerplate code, such as checking for `isset($_POST[X])`.

If you implemented your own validation framework/class then it would make your application prettier, and certainly reduce the lines of code the API caller has to have.

In the end, what are you trying to achieve? Are you building an application for a client that will be used once, and not ever updated, if so no need to make the code pretty. If you take pride in the code, and want it to be impressive, and want to learn, then yes, build your own validation framework/class. Even though there are existing code bases out there to solve this problem, building it yourself will only be a catalyst for growth for you as a developer/engineer.

Last, but certainly not least, there is no "proper" way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to do this, to emphasize the multiplechoice-ness of the possibility:

```
if (!$_POST['title']) { callExit("No title."); }
elseif (!$_POST['body']) { callExit("No body."); }
```

Alternatively, if you have lots of fields, do a loop:

```
$required_fields=array("title"=>"No title", "body"=>"You are missing a body parameter");
foreach ($required_fields AS $fieldname=>$message) {
   if (!$_POST[$fieldname]) { callExit($message) }
```